# How to use Worksheets_activate to trigger any sheet without putting it in each sheet

Tags: excel, events, vba

I have a random number of sheets and I want to call a event when I change the selected sheet. To use Worksheet_Activate is needed to add the code in each sheet. There is a way to apply the event to whole workbook?

What I know:

```
'Code added in sheet_X
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call DoMyStuffs
End Sub
```

What I want:

```
'Code added in ThisWorkbook
Private Sub AnyWorksheet_Activate()
    Call DoMyStuffs
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To"). You might also want to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour "Magical Mystery Tour") and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: I changed my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in thisworkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

End Sub
```